# Searching for specific file types in a file, using a link

Tags: python, url

When I run my code and input the URL it's using to pull the data it just gives me "Image requests account for 0.0% of all requests". It's skipping over taking in the data and I don't get why.

```
#search for hits that are an image file
file = downloadData(url)
reader = csv.reader(file.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
heading = next(reader, None)
for line in reader:
    hits = 0
    image_hits = 0
    hits += 1
    if re.search(r"(\.jpeg|\.gif|\.PNG)$", str(line)):
        image_hits += 1

percentage = (image_hits / hits) * 100

print("Image requests account for {:.1f}% of all requests".format(percentage))
```

Comment: Apparently `image_hits` is 0 (or at least very small compared to `hits`).

Comment: You're resetting `image_hits` to zero every loop iteration, so the highest number of hits you will see is 1 if it happened to be in the last line. Place the declarations _before_ the loop.